# Any tips on how to get better at PvP in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Any tips on how to get better at PvP in Minecraft? I'm still really bad even though I'm a veteran and have been playing for over 2 years now. Any tips are much appreciated. No insults please. :)

Comment: Please add some info like what weapon you want to use and make your question a little less broad.

Answer (score 1):

The same way to get to Carnegie Hall:  Practice.

Don't confuse longevity with skill: Just because you've been doing something a long time, doesn't mean you're good. I played Quake 3 multiplayer when it came out (yes, I'm old) and it was the best way to improve my game. Play against people better than you.

Answer (score -2):

One way to gain an advantage if you don't know this already is to strafe. While someone's coming at you with there sword you try to get behind them using the A and D key and slice open their back.

Comment: You can't "slice open a back". Also getting behind someone is really difficult.

Comment: sorry. I know you can't slice open backs. when I said that I meant just once you get behind them spam at their back.

Comment: Getting behind them is not really easy

Comment: ya it is. it's either easy or the people i was versing where noobs cuz i suck at pvp

Comment: Whats that supposed to mean?

Comment: I mean that it must be easy to get behind people cuz I stink a pvp and I can get behind some people